S'forim on Gemara written by a S'fardi in the past 100-200 yrs
Does anyone know of any peirushim on shas, and specifically I need a perush on masechet Gittin to be part of it, written by a S'fardi rav who had lived in the past 100-200 years? I heard that R' ben-Tzion Abba Shaul has such a peirush, but he does not have one on Gittin. I am not seeking something that has halachot Gittin, rather a commentary ordered by the daf on masechet Gittin.
Thank you.

I will put Kikar LaAden here, by the Chida, as a comment, because it's just a tad older than 200 years, and it doesn't have anything on Gittin: https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Yerushalmi/Commentary/Kikar%20LaAden%20on%20Jerusalem%20Talmud

R. Avraham Hakohen Yitzchaki of Tunis (1789-1864) authored Mishmerot Kehunah on Shas, including chiddushim on Gittin.
His student (for a few months), R. Shelomo Dana (1850-1913) also authored chiddushim on Shas, including Gittin, in a book entitled Shalmei Todah.

I tried to find the 2 Sforim for purchase online but couldn't find them. (I want a physical copy.) Do you know where I can find them?

Looks like Mishmerot Kehunah is available for purchase from Yeshivat Kisei Rahamim https://www.ykr.org.il/product/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%92-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%AA/
